# Excel Sendkeys not working

Tags: vba, excel

i have the following code which should minimize the Excel 2010 ribbon. I have placed in the
`workbook_open` event code :

```
Dim iheight As Integer
iheight = Application.CommandBars.Item("Ribbon").Height
If iheight > 100 Then
   Application.SendKeys ("^{F1}")
End If
```

However when i run it, it opens excel help! i have tried removing the brackets but getting the same result.

Any ideas?

cheers

Comment: as far as i know, **F1** will always open the **Help** in any Office-Products.

Comment: Hi, I'm aware of that, but this code sends Ctrl+F1

Comment: you are right, somehow i did not really notice the ^.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking a wild guess here that you are trying to test this code in the VBA editor? Either by clicking the play button or pressing F5?

This won't work if you test in the VBA editor because Ctrl + F1 **does** bring up the help menu.

What you need to do is call the routine from inside excel, so excel is the active window. Simply create a shape and assign it the routine to test, then invoke it in whichever way you were going to.

Remember what `sendkeys` does, it just mimics the keyboard

You can lose the brackets, although they wont make any difference

My test code, worked OK:

```
Sub test6()
Dim iheight As Integer
iheight = Application.CommandBars.Item("Ribbon").Height
If iheight > 100 Then
   Application.SendKeys ("^{F1}")
End If
End Sub

Sub MinRibbon()
Call test6 'assigned to a shape on an excel sheet
End Sub
```

You could just try saving your workbook and then closing it and opening it (as you have this set to run on `workbook_open`), I see no reason why this wouldn't work

Comment: SilverShotBee, you are right! it doesnt work in the editor. What i ended up doing was adding a line of code in workbook_open to select cell A1. Then in the worksheet selection_change event code, calling test6. That minimized the Ribbon. Many thanks for that pointer.

Answer (score 1):

you can try following, to hide the ribbon bar:

```
Sub hideRibbonIfVisible() 
   If RibbonVisibility = 0 Then
      CommandBars.ExecuteMso "MinimizeRibbon" 
   End If
End Sub 

Function RibbonVisibility() As Integer 
   RibbonVisibility = (CommandBars("Ribbon").Controls(1).Height < 100) 
End Function
```

Comment: hi, Thanks Ben. This works too. im guessing credit to Ron de Bruin at http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win003.htm

Comment: UPDATE: CARE if you use this method ! just tested it on a different computer and got an error. Does the "ExecuteMso" line depend on a particular reference being available?